# Does atomic particles have smell?

Tags: atoms, molecules, matter

Do atomic particles like Sulphur or Hydrogen have their own distinct smell? Is the distinctive smell of Hydrogen Sulphide a combination of the smells of Hydrogen and Sulphur ? If not, then how do molecules like Hydrogen Sulphide generate the sensation of smell ?

Comment: The physiological smell of hydrogen sulphide is not a combination of the individual smells of hydrogen and sulphur. Instead, the molecular shape of hydrogen sulphide allows it to bind to an [olfactory sensory neuron][1] (OSN) in the lining of the nasal cavity, which then triggers the sensation of smell. This sensation is specific to hydrogen sulphide - neither hydrogen nor sulphur on its own would trigger the OSN.

Comment: Smell is a physiological (neural) effect of chemical reactions taking place at the so-called "smell receptors" in the nose. This is a mesoscopic/macroscopic effect, you cannot assign a neural reaction due to one molecule. You need to have very many.

Comment: definution of smell "he faculty or power of perceiving odours or scents by means of the organs in the nose.
"a highly developed sense of smell"  ..Biology not physics

Comment: Biology is applied chemistry. Chemistry is applied physics. And, of course, physics is applied mathematics :)